# File.Open error when the file is in the external USB drive

Tags: c#, .net

I received the file open error when the file in the external USB hard drive. However when I copied the file to my local hard driver, it is good.  Everything is the same. Any possible reason? I am running under Windows 7.

Comment: Would you mind pasting some code?

Comment: Also, the entire Exception type, message and stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: I found I have to open visual studio as administrator, then the File.Open is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the information you provided, it can be:

1. Wrong path to the device - you give the right path when the file is on your hard drive, and the wrong one when it is on the USB hard drive.
2. Some timeout exception - if the USB is too slow to repond.
3. Permissions of the user, that starts your application.

Comment: I found I have to open visual studio as administrator, then the File.Open is ok

Comment: Then mark this as the answer.  Danail said "#3. Permissions...", and that's what you found. +1 to Danail.